# Slf4j logging not logging to file in wildfly

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, wildfly-10

I have following the parent pom

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.7</version>
            </dependency>
```

The resources folder in the services module has following logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">

    <property name="MY_HOME" value="C:\Users\" />

<!--
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>${MY_HOME}/logs/mylog.log</File>
-->
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>C:/Users/logs/abc.log</File>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <FileNamePattern>C:/Users/logs/my.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
      <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender> 

  <root level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

And in the class it is getting called as this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

...
...
  private static final Logger sl4jLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceBean.class);
    ...
    ...

        sl4jLogger.debug("debug : show up in logger");
        sl4jLogger.info("info : show up in logger");
        sl4jLogger.error("error : show up in logger");
        sl4jLogger.trace("trace : show up in logger");
        sl4jLogger.warn("warn : show up in logger");
```

Only the below are displayed on the console, but there is no log file created in anywhere.

```
12:33:07,262 INFO  [ServiceBean] (default task-63) info : show up in logger 

12:33:07,262 ERROR [ServiceBean] (default task-63) error : show up in logger

12:33:07,263 WARN  [ServiceBean] (default task-63) warn : show up in logger
```

AppServer jboss wildfly - 10.0.0

I also added/tried several different version of jboss-deployment-structure.xml to webapp/META-INF/ folder.
But none of these worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

<!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>-->


<!--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
-->

<!--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
-->

    <!--
    <jboss-deployment-structure>
        <deployment>
            <exclusions>
                <module name="org.slf4j" />
                <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
                <module name="org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j" />
                <module name="org.slf4j.ext" />
                <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            </exclusions>
        </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>-->
```

The project is made of several diff modules. A couple of wars, jar, ejb. All these are wrapped in ear. Is that the issue ?

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The slf4j loggers are working they're just not bound to the log manager you expect them to be bound to. While you're including the slf4j dependencies you're deployment is likely using the slf4j module provided by the server which is bound to the JBoss Log Manager. The log messages you're seeing are controlled by the [logging subsystem](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration).

The best option is to use the logging subsystem to configure logging. If you use the web console or CLI you'll get the ability to make changes at runtime without having to restart the server or redeploy your application.

If you really want to use logback in your deployment the easiest way is to [exclude the logging subsystem](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly#ClassLoadinginWildFly-JBossDeploymentStructureFile) from your deployment. Then the dependencies you provided will be used and slf4j should bind to logback.

The other option is to change the `add-logging-api-dependencies` attribute to `false` on the logging subsystem. This will stop the logging API's from being added to all deployments that are deployed.

```
/subsystem=logging:write-attribute(name=add-logging-api-dependencies, value=false)
```

Comment: I had added jboss-deployment-structure.xml but that did not help. I updated the question.

Comment: It sounds like you're using an EAR so you'll need to exclude the subsystem for each subdeployment too.